# Webpack doesn't recognize node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I already add `node` to the `types` field in my `tsconfig.json`. Also, I did `npm i @types/node`. But webpack doesn't recognize node in `webpack.config.ts`.

Errors:

- Cannot find name 'require'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.ts(2580)
- Cannot find name '__dirname'.ts(2304)

This is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2015",
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "typeRoots": ["/node_modules/@types", "@types"],
    "types": ["node"]
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*.tsx", "./src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["./node_modules", "./**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

Comment: npm install @types/node --save-dev and replace  "typeRoots" value with "typeRoots": [ "../node_modules/@types" ] and try again.

Comment: @BabakYaghoobi Thanks for your advice. But it still doesn't work. My `node_modules` is located in the same directory as `tsconfig.json`.